# Different post style

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to style wordpress posts differently, so I decide it to based on post id number odd and even to have different CSS class. So I wrote this code to check is id of post odd or even in content.php:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php $num = the_ID(); ?>
    <?php if($num % 2 == 0){
        echo "<h1> It's even </h1>";
    }else{
        echo "<h1>It's odd</h1>";
    }



    ?>
    .....
</article>
```

Problem is that it always says "It's even", even it is odd, For example, post number is 33, and it says that is even. So, what is the problem with my approach, is there any better way to achieve what I need ?

Comment: what about nth_child css selector, will that not work?

Comment: i think the_ID() is not returning the correct value because the if statement is correct

Comment: [`the_ID`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) will echo the ID. You need [`get_the_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) to assign it to a variable. Of course, the post ID will never be consistently odd/even so you should not rely on it. Use `nth-child` in CSS or use a `++$i` in your loop to track the true odd/even of the posts.

Comment: agree with @Kirk Beard, the_content(), the_excerpt(), the_ID() will be null/blank , when You want to save it to variable, You need to use get_the_content(), get_the_excerpt(), get_the_ID() etc. ... https://codex.wordpress.org is Your friend

Comment: This works: <?php
 $id = get_the_ID() % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'od';
 
echo "<h1>" . $id . "</h1>"; ?>

Answer (score 0):

=== 0

You're or need to compare same types, not different types.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the_ID() is from wordpress I'm hoping maybe changing the function would net you the results you want as the code above in theory works from my testing but the_ID() as commented would most likely be the issue.

Try using get_the_ID() as it returns the ID of the post you are on.

the_ID():
**Note**: This function displays the ID of the post, to return the ID use get_the_ID().

From this I am assuming the_ID() also produces an echo '';

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

```
<?php $num = get_the_ID(); ?>
```